# Adding Authorization to one of my SignalR Hubs leads to WebSocket failing to connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using a SignlaR Hub to handle matchmaking for an online chess application, and I'm trying to restrict usage of the hub with JWT authorization.

```
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class GameHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;
        public static List<Player> _Players = new List<Player>();

        public GameHub(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {   
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
        public async Task JoinQueue(string userEmail)
        {
            Player player = context.Players.Where(x => x.Email == userEmail).FirstOrDefault();
            Player player2 = null;  
            if (player != null)
            {
                _Players.Add(player);
            }
            else
                return;
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("QueuePlayerCountUpdate", _Players.Count);
            
            bool foundMatch = false;
            int eloRange = 50;
            while (!foundMatch) {
                if (_Players.Where(x => player.Elo - eloRange <= x.Elo && 
                x.Elo <= player.Elo + eloRange && 
                x.PlayerId != player.PlayerId).Any())
                    player2 = _Players.Where(x => player.Elo - eloRange <= x.Elo 
&& x.Elo <=                  player.Elo + eloRange).FirstOrDefault();
                if(player2 == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    eloRange += 50;
                }
                else
                {
                    _Players.Remove(player);
                    _Players.Remove(player2);
                    foundMatch = true;
                    Clients.Caller.SendAsync("MatchFound",player2.Email);
                    Clients.User(player2.AspNetUserId).SendAsync("MatchFound", player.Email);
                }
                  
                   
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the code behind the hub,

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

namespace BackEnd_ASP.NET
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                var frontendURL = Configuration.GetValue<string>("frontend_url");
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
                });
            });

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().
                AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived = context =>
                        {
                            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                            {
                                context.Token = accessToken;
                            }
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = false,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
                        (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["keyjwt"])),
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };
                    
                });

           
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }


            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors();  
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<GameHub>("/GameHub");

            });
            app.UseAuthorization();

           
        }
    }
}
```

this is the startup
and this is the connection initialization

```
 const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().
            withUrl("https://localhost:7244/GameHub",{
                accessTokenFactory: ()=> {return `bearer ${token}`},  
                skipNegotiation: true,
                transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
              }).
            configureLogging(LogLevel.Information).build();
```

If i simply remove the Authorization tag everything works as expected. I have tried moving the authorization tag to the endpoint, or having it both on the endpoint and the entire hub, i have also tried removing bearer from the token,i have tried removing the skip negotiation option,and tried modifying the

```
OnMessageReceived = context =>
                        {
                            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                            {
                                context.Token = accessToken;
                            }
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
```

in a couple of ways, none of which have worked. I have made sure to have sockets enabled in IIS Windows server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below and the issue will be fixed. Please check the official doc : 
[Authentication and authorization in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#built-in-jwt-authentication)

[Middleware Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order)

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }


        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();  

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<GameHub>("/GameHub");

        });
        //app.UseAuthorization();

       
    }
```